# ¿Cómo convertir meses (String) a un valor int? Java

Tags: java

tal y como dice la pregunta. Tengo un programa que muestra un **JOptionPane** con un array **String** que contiene los doce meses:

```
String[] arrayMeses = new String[] {
            "Enero",
            "Febrero",
            "Marzo", 
            "Abril",
            "Mayo",
            "Junio",
            "Julio",
            "Agosto",
            "Septiembre",
            "Octubre",
            "Noviembre",
            "Diciembre"
    };
    mes = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Seleccione mes de nacimiento:", "Mes de nacimiento", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, arrayMeses, arrayMeses[0]);
    //Conversion mesObject a mesString
    mesString = mes.toString();
```

Como pueden observar, el **JOptionPane** me da un **Object**, este lo paso a **String** y ese valor irá en el constructor de otra clase.
El problema es que al final que el usuario introduce su fecha de nacimiento, debo calcular su edad y dejarla en otra variable.
He revisado algunas clases, pero todas me piden que el mes aparezca en un primitivo **int**.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cuál sería la mejor forma de hacer esta conversión?, es decir; asignar a cada mes un valor numérico.

He pensado en usar una serie de if o switch, pero se me hace poco «profesional», ¿alguien tiene una alternativa a este situación?

Agradezco su atención y ayuda :)

Comment: No entiendo. Si el usuario como dices, introduce su fecha de nacimiento, ¿para qué le pides el mes aparte? ¿por qué si necesitas sólo el mes no lo tomas de la fecha de nacimiento que introdujo o va a introducir más tarde, subrayando que esa fecha se guardará en un objeto del tipo `Date` del cual puedes tomar el mes como quieras, donde quieras y cuando quieras
? Esos programas que hacen repetir cosas al usuario no son profesionales. Los programas deben existir para facilitar las cosas, no para complicarlas.

Comment: Bueno, puse 3 menús desplegables, esa parte del código corresponde a la del mes, mi idea era precisamente que el usuario leyera los meses y evitara poner un número.

Comment: Pero si se requiere la fecha de nacimiento el usuario, ¿por qué no le pides la fecha completa y la guardas en un objeto del tipo `Date`? Así le pides el dato una sola vez. Luego, si necesitas sólo el valor entero del mes, usas ese objeto del tipo  `Date` y lo extraes. Y, para facilitar las cosas al usuario puedes implementar también algo así como un `DatePicker`, o sea que muestre un calendario donde escoja la fecha o un combobox con los años de nacimiento ordenados en forma descendente, pidiéndole que esocoja el año y luego mostrar un calendario de ese año. Pero eso es otra cosa.

Answer (score 1):

Si no quieres complicarte la vida, lo más fácil es la estructura switch.

Si quieres complicarte la vida, puedes usar algunas clases para el manejo de fechas de las que implementa la API, pero aún así tienes que realizar la conversión de string a int.

Si vas a hacerlo en modo gráfico y quieres hacerlo un poco más "elegante", en lugar de un JOptionPane, echa un vistazo al JComboBox. Parece más adecuado.

Si quieres hacer una interfaz gráfica en condiciones, écha un vistazo a la librería [JCalendar](https://toedter.com/jcalendar/).

Answer (score 0):

```
public int convierteMes(Object seleccion) {
    if (seleccion instanceof String) {
        String mesSeleccionado = (String)seleccion;
        for (int mes = 0; mes < arrayMeses.length; mes++) {
            if (mesSeleccionado.equals(arrayMeses[mes])) {
                return mes;
               //puedes retornar mes+1 si quieres que enero sea uno
               //pero usualmente enero se toma como cero,...
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Cabe notar que esto funciona, siempre y cuando el arreglo lo deje en el orden correcto. De lo contrario el número asignado será erroneo